# How to compute the conductance of partitioning network in R

Tags: r, igraph, modularity

I would like to compare two partitioning network metric -- modularity and conductance --  step by step. Modularity is build-in function of the igraph, but igraph does not include the Conductance function. The example code is shown below.

[Conductance](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/index.php?s=10.1145/2350190.2350193) (Yang and Leskovec, 2012): f(S) = c/(2m+c) measures the fraction of total edge volume that points outside the cluster, S is the set of nodes, m the number of edges in S, m = |{(u, v) ∈ E : u ∈ S, v ∈ S}|; and c, the number of
edges on the boundary of S, c = |{(u, v) ∈ E : u ∈ S, v not ∈ S}|.

[Modularity](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/index.php?s=10.1145/2350190.2350193) (Yang and Leskovec, 2012): f(S) = (m − E(m)/4 is the difference between m, the number of edges between nodes in S and E(m), the expected number of such edges in a random graph with identical degree sequence.

A higher f(S) score means that a set of nodes more closely  resembles the connectivity pattern of a community.

In contrast of modularity that was proposed by M. Newman, there was an accepted standard for the results of community detection, [Yang and Leskovec (2012)](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/index.php?s=10.1145/2350190.2350193) found that Conductance could provide the best performance in identifying ground-truth communities.

```
library(igraph) 
g <- make_graph( ~ A-B-C-D-A, E-A:B:C:D,
                      F-G-H-I-F, J-F:G:H:I,
                      K-L-M-N-K, O-K:L:M:N,
                      P-Q-R-S-P, T-P:Q:R:S,
                      B-F, E-J, C-I, L-T, O-T, M-S,
                      C-P, C-L, I-L, I-P)
gnc <- walktrap.community(g)
m <- vector()
con <- vector()
for (s in 0: nrow(gnc$merges)) {

memb <- cutat(gnc, steps=s)
m <- c(m, modularity (g, memb, weights=NULL))

g2<-make_clusters(g, memb)

  intra<-0
  extra<-0 
    for(i in 1:length(E(g))) 
        {
         ifelse(crossing(g2, g)[i]==FALSE, intra<-intra+1, extra<-extra+1)
    }
con <-c(con, extra/(2*intra+extra)) 

 } 
windows()
par(mfrow=c(1:2))
plot(0:(length(m)-1), m, col="blue",xlab="Steps",ylab="Modularity")
plot(0:(length(con)-1), con, col="blue",xlab="Steps",ylab="Conductance")
```

My code does not have syntactical error. But I concerned about the result, I think that I have a logical error. A modularity curve has the maximum value 0.4583 inside the steps' range (on the step with no.=18), but conductance curve has extremum 0 on the right boundary (on the step with no.=20). 
Conductance is decreasing on all merge/split steps.

```
> max(m)
[1] 0.4583333 # index =18
> max(con)
[1] 0 # index = 20
```

Could someone please give me an idea where is error in my code?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know conductance is only defined when a single cut of the network is made, i.e. there are two communities.  If you have a general definition for k communities you will probably need the number of edge crossings which you can get by supplying a communities object to the crossing function:     crossing(gnc,g)

Comment: @RyanHaunfelder, thanks you for comment, I have updated the question. In common case we can detect k>2 communities and this partitions will be define two edges sets: 1) m = |{(u, v) ∈ E : u ∈ S, v ∈ S}| and 2) c= |{(u, v) ∈ E : u ∈ S, v ∈ S1}|, where (S and S1) equal to the total edge volume V.

Comment: Ok, using the definitions you have provided, a small value of conductance and a large value of modularity will indicate a strong community structure.  Note that if there are communities present in the graph then m, the number of edges that within a community will be large compared to c, the number of edges between communities.  Therefore, there should be no surprise that conductance is decreasing at every step.  Your code appears to be computing the correct quantity.